# Array to string conversion error, how to store data from a form using laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel, forms

**many to many relationship between tables posts and features**

**PostController**

```
public function create()
{
    $features = Feature::all();
    return view('form', compact('features'));
}


public function store(Request $request)
{
    $post = Post::create($request->except(['features']));
    $post->features()->sync($request->feature);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    @foreach($features as $feature)
    <div class="col-6 col-md-3 mt-2 ">
            <div class="form-check form-check-inline mr-4 pr-4">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="{{$feature}}" name="feature[]" value="{{$feature->id}}">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="{{$feature}}">{{$feature->feature}}</label>
            </div>
    </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

**FeatureSeeder**

```
 public function run()
{
    Feature::create(['feature'=>'Backup Camera']);
    Feature::create(['feature'=>'Cruise Control']);
    Feature::create(['feature'=>'Power Steering']);
    Feature::create(['feature'=>'Hands-Free']);
    Feature::create(['feature'=>'Heated Seats']);
    Feature::create(['feature'=>'Keyless-Entry']);
    Feature::create(['feature'=>'Sunroof']);
}
```

**if the question is not well formed or any information needed feel free to comment it,**
** thanks in advance**

Comment: Do you know what part in your code is producing the error?

Comment: i think so, data type error OR! @aceraven777

Comment: Where are you seeing the error? When you click save button?

Comment: yes @aceraven777

Answer (score 0):

Try removing compact() from PostController:

```
public function create()
{
    $features = Feature::all();
    return view('form', ['features' => $features]);
}
```

Comment: i cant i have other data that im passing, any other options

Answer (score 0):

I think your error in:

```
<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="{{$feature}}" name="feature[]" value="{{$feature->id}}">
 <label class="form-check-label" for="{{$feature}}">{{$feature->feature}}</label>
```

Please try this:

```
<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="{{$feature->id}}" name="feature[]" value="{{$feature->id}}">
 <label class="form-check-label" for="{{$feature->id}}">{{$feature->feature}}</label>
```